# Why webpack adding comments

Tags: javascript, webpack, comments

I'm confused about that, why webpack adding comments to the bundle file like this:

```
/******/ function blabla() {
/******/ }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does this to help with debugging etc. -- the comments tell you what source file the function came from, and what module # it's being loaded by (at runtime). If you use the Uglify plugin, it will strip out the comments.